# Factor inside argument

Tags: core-language

How do you use Factor so that it will factor expressions inside the arguments of some bigger expression.

For example

```
 Factor[ Cos[t w - t z]]
```

gives

```
 Cos[t w - t z]
```

but i would like it to give:

```
 Cos[t(w - z)]
```

Comment: `Simplify[Cos[t w - t z]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Map` it:

```
Map[Factor, Cos[t w - t z]]
```

Or with infix notation:

```
Factor /@ Cos[t w - t z]
```

Comment: For more complicated expressions, `MapAll` may prove useful, working on all levels: compare `Factor //@ Cos[t w - t z + Sin[a x + a y]]` to `Factor /@ Cos[t w - t z + Sin[a x + a y]]`

Comment: Thanks @VF1, that is the general question i was trying to address

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Collect instead of Factor.

```
Cos[Collect[t w - t z, t]]
```

This gives:

```
Cos[t (w - z)]
```

Hope it helps.